# Get all instances of a class

Tags: c#, reflection

Is there a way to get all instances of a class in C# with reflection?
For example, lets say we have a class Point.

```
Point p1 = new Point(5,5);
Point p2 = new point(2,2);
```

Is there a way to get all instances of this with reflection?
I have seen something like this but it doesn't work for me.

```
return (from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
        where t.BaseType == (typeof(T)) && t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null
        select (T)Activator.CreateInstance(t)).ToList();
```

Comment: What do you mean all instance? Find all instances on the heap that haven't been garbage collected irrespective of whether they're still reference-able?

Comment: The instances who are still reference-able. if it's possible.

Comment: `Is there a way to get all instances of this with reflection?` **NO** *You* should keep track of instances...

Comment: It's not really possible.. What is the problem you're trying to solve with this? There is likely a better, simpler, solution.

Comment: Reflection is about metadata not instances, you have to use debugger or profiler functions to achieve this.

Comment: [Can I get the instances of alive objects of a certain type in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123272/can-i-get-the-instances-of-alive-objects-of-a-certain-type-in-c)

Comment: You can get some pointers from [answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2934392/1149773), but they involve unmanaged code.

Comment: @Eser the irony, of course, being that if you track them: you actively change which ones are alive

Comment: @MarcGravell Maybe *WeakReference* can help here :)