# Is is possible to keep track of the current number of instances of a class?

Tags: c#, class, .net-core, static

In .NET, I understand that there is a garbage collector that will manage the memory that's being used during the execution of a program. This means that objects will be cleaned up when they go unused.

I was wondering if I could keep a static counter in a certain class that automatically updates when instances of that class are created or garbage collected. For example, if I create some instances of some `CountableInstance` class, then they could each have an `InstanceIndex` that keeps track of their *current* position based on when they were created.

Such a flow could look like this:

0. Program starts
1. `CountableInstance ctble0` is created with `InstanceIndex == 0`
2. `CountableInstance ctble1` is created with `InstanceIndex == 1`
3. `CountableInstance ctble2` is created with `InstanceIndex == 2`
4. `CountableInstance ctble1` goes unused and gets garbage collected

- `ctble0`'s index stays the same
- `ctble2`'s index becomes `1`

5. Program ends

I'm guessing that keeping track of the number of `CountableInstance` instances would look like this:

```cs
public class CountableInstance
{
    public static int total = 0;
    public CountableInstance()
    {
        InstanceIndex = total;
        total++; // Next instance will have an increased InstanceIndex
    }
    public CountableInstance(...) : this()
    {
        // Constructor logic goes here
    }

    public int InstanceIndex { get; private set; }
}
```

This takes care of how many instances there are and it also assigns the correct index to each new object. However, this implementation misses the logic that should happen when an instance is garbage collected.

If possible, how could I implement it? Would it also work to keep track of instances of objects that use a particular interface?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? See [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/299295)

Comment: Another option is to delegate to another class the responsibility of creating/releasing instances and maintaining the count by class type. An IoC container for instance could do the job.

Comment: Why do you need to know this? It's a very unusual requirement, to say the least.

Comment: It's purely out of curiosity, but if I had to come up with some kind of practical scenario to use this, I guess I could use the instance index to check for equality or something.

Comment: I am not able to comment yet, this answer might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123272/can-i-get-the-instances-of-alive-objects-of-a-certain-type-in-c

Comment: There are other ways to check for equality between objects. Not sure how a counter would help with that anyway, tbh. I think there's really no obvious way to do it simply because it generally isn't necessary for an application to know about _all_ instances of a given class. Usually if people want to keep lists of objects, they put them into a `List` or array,.

Comment: @ADyson yeah, I just came up with a contrived example off the top of my head

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve the gist of this as below, but this seems like a bad idea IMO; in particular:

1. finalizers aren't free (and neither is `IDisposable.Dispose()`)
2. you can create objects *without ever running a constructor* (if you try hard enough)

Anyway, code:

```cs
public class CountableInstance
{
    static int s_Total, s_Alive;
    public CountableInstance() {
        // need a separate total vs alive so we don't give duplicate
        // InstanceIndex, at least for the first 4 billion objects
        InstanceIndex = Interlocked.Increment(ref s_Total);
        Interlocked.Increment(ref s_Alive);
    }
    ~CountableInstance() {
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref s_Alive);
    }
    public int InstanceIndex { get; }
    public static int Alive => Volatile.Read(ref s_Alive);
    public static int Total => Volatile.Read(ref s_Total);
}
```

Comment: Interesting code, it makes sense that this requires some async stuff but it's still more alien than I'd expected!

Comment: @JansthcirlU, I dont see how it requesires async code

Comment: @JansthcirlU it's not async. The `Interlocked` stuff is thread safe; atomic operations.

Comment: @JansthcirlU, Atomically increase or decrease an integer value

Comment: Oh, I see, I figured it was async because it was part of `Threading`

Comment: How will these change the IDs of the other entities?

Comment: @mjwills I'm working on the view that it would be a very bad idea to change ids

Comment: @mjwills I said I would edit my question but it's actually a pretty tough puzzle

Comment: @MarcGravell I've marked your answer as the right one but if you don't mind, I might edit it once I figure out how to change the IDs

Comment: @JansthcirlU IMO that's just a really really bad idea; there is no efficient way of doing that, and there are lots of *very very inefficient* (or actively dangerous) ways of doing it

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like this:

```
public class CountableInstance : IDisposable
{
    public static int total = 0;
    ...




    public void Dispose()
    {
         //total--;
         //Edit:
         Interlocked.Decrement(total);
    }

}
```

this would keep track of what happens within your application. but as far as i know garbage collection could still be delayed to a later point long after Dispose.

Comment: What's the difference between calling `Dispose` or calling a class's `Finalizer` as in Marc Gravell's answer?

Comment: @JansthcirlU `Dispose()` is called explicitly through your code, usually via `using` statments; finalizers are called by the GC. `Dispose()` is more "timely", by which I mean: your code can *say* when it has finished; GC happens when it wants

Answer (score 0):

If you want your indexes of your created instances to change if one instance is removed, you'll need to store them in a list. See this solution:

```
public class CountableInstance : IDisposable
{
    private static List<CountableInstance> instances = new List<CountableInstance>();
    
    public CountableInstance()
    {
        InstanceIndex = instances.Count;
        instances.Add(this);
    }
    
    public void Dispose()
    {
        instances.Remove(this);
        for(int i = InstanceIndex; i < instances.Count; i++)
        {
            instances[i].InstanceIndex = i;
        }
    }
    
    public int InstanceIndex { get; private set; }
}
```

Note that since the instances are stored in the list, they will never get garbage collected before you call `Dispose()`. You'll have to call `Dispose()` manually if you don't need your object anymore, which let's you lose a big advantage of garbage collection. Also note that this solution is *not thread safe*.

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/A1LptG

Comment: This seems just actively dangerous; I would not recommend this approach

Comment: @MarcGravell But it is the only answer, that actually satisfies OP's requirement to change indexes of the other instance when any instance is removed. But fortunately, OP asked only for curiosity, so there is a good chance that he will never use this approach.